# Ampersand issue when checking term name in SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powershell-4.0

I am creating terms into SharePoint using PowerShell online. I have no issues in terms of adding new term for the first time.

If I check next time if the term exists and the ampersand `&amp` converts to different hex in SharePoint as a result it fails in the comparison in PowerShell.

I found the [`TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName(String)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.normalizename?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_Taxonomy_TaxonomyItem_NormalizeName_System_String_)
which describes that I can normalize my text. But I am getting an error

> Unable to find type [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy].

What I have in my PowerShell script is:

```
$Termname = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy]::NormalizeName($Context, $Termname)
```

Answer (score 1):

When executing this

$Termname = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy]::NormalizeName($Context, $Termname)

will get empty but i have to execute the context separately like :

$context.ExecuteQuery().

This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

[`NormalizeName` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.normalizename.aspx) belongs to [`TaxonomyItem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.taxonomy.taxonomyitem.aspx),  Here is an example how to utilize it in PowerShell:

```
$result = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.TaxonomyItem]::NormalizeName($Context, $Termname)
$Context.ExecuteQuery() #query needs to be executed in order to retrieve NormalizeName value 
Write-Host $result.Value
```

Sometimes it might be more convenient (from performance perspective) to avoid extra request to the server, then the following function could be utilized instead:

```
Function Normalize-Name([string]$Name) {
    if (!$Name) {
       return $null
    }  
    $trimSpacesRegex = new-object regex("\\s+",([System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase -bor [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled))
    return $trimSpacesRegex.Replace($Name, " ").Replace('&', [char]0xff06).Replace('"', [char]0xff02)
}
```

And

```
$encTermname = Normalize-Name -Name $Termname
```

should return the same result as `TaxonomyItem.NormalizeName` function